# ElasticSearch get top 2 results per specific term in aggregations

Tags: java, sql, json, elasticsearch, kibana

Given this query, i want to retrieve and limit only to top 2 cities from each country.
So, **given the most popular country, retrieve top 2 cities, then next country, top 2 cities and etcera.**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_city_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.city_id",
        "size": 999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_country_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user.country_id",
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "user_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user.name",
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user.category": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how you decide top city or based on which field or param you decide top city

Comment: @SagarPatel That query will return top cities id by count in desc order (thats the default order by ES), but i just want to limit the ocurrence by country in only 2 cities, so i can get top 2 cities from one country, then 2 cities from next country, etc

Comment: please check, i have posted answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below aggregation query give you 2 city per country.

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "user_country_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.country_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_city_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user.city_id",
            "size": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was correct! One question, the "doc_count_error_upper_bound" in response field is not zero, i was told that setting size = 999 in the terms aggs fix thats, but i want to query with size = 10 as you posted but without count_errors...

Comment: @JuanCruz `doc_count_error_upper_bound` is per document bucket count error and it is depends on other fector like number of shards, number of documents etc. You can check offical documenrtation for same. size = 999 will work currently but once the documents count increase it might not work.